# Haskell: getting the size of a image

Tags: haskell

I'm new to Haskell and asked a professor of mine for some Exercise to help with my learning. He gave me something on image manipulation.
I have several images created using strings in Haskell, e.g.

```
pic :: Int -> Pic 
pic 1 = ["  ####   ",
         " ##  ##  ",
         "  ####   "]
```

I want to obtain the image size e.g. width 9 height 3 in (9,3) format. 
Defining it as

`sizePic :: Pic -> (Int, Int)`

The height is simply using the Length function.
Height :: Pic -> Int
Height = length

The width i'm having some trouble with.
Width :: Pic -> Int
Width =

I simply want the length of the head to be shown (all strings are equal length)

any ideas.

Comment: try `maximum . map length` or if you're sure the picture is a valid and well-dimensioned one: `length . first`

Comment: @Carsten `max` is binary, `maximum` takes a list

Comment: @chi ... thanks (self-facepalm) - this happens if you don't check and rely on your stupid brain ;)

Comment: Thanks That's got me the width. Still having a problem getting it defined as sizePic :: Pic -> (Int, Int)

Comment: @Carsten AFAIK, giving clear answers to homework-like questions isn't considered to be a good thing.

Comment: @arrowd 1: homework is no problem here - 2: it's not the answer, 3: my homework-senses did not *tingle* here

Comment: If you want the `length` of the `head`, surely there's a straightforward way to get it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is not going to help you as a beginner, but to give a taste of what can be done

```
> import Control.Arrow
> (length &&& (length . head)) s
(3,9)
```

you can write your version as

```
type Pic = [String]

sizePic :: Pic -> (Int, Int)
sizePic [] = (0,0)  
sizePic (x:xs) = (1+length xs, length x)
```

Answer (score 1):

Hint №1: Strings in Haskell are lists of `Char`s. That is, every line in your "image" is `[Char]`.

Hint №2: To get a width you need to apply `length` to the first (or last, or any other) line.

Comment: I like your input, I think it's more constructive than an answer, but as I just implied, I don't think this is an answer.